# How do I install Turbo Pascal?

Tags: installation, 10.04, pascal

I'm reading this [tutorial](http://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/tutor1.txt). I need a turbo pascal, can anyone say me how to install turbo pascal in Ubuntu 10.04?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for `free pascal` in the `Ubuntu Software Center`, that will fit your needs.

Comment: I have installed it, how do i run the sample programs? What is the extension of pascal, is it .p?

Comment: yeah, it is p, just open it with free pascal and run any code you might want.

Comment: I always used `.pas` for my Pascal programs.

Comment: Doesnt mather, as long as you can load them and run on the compiler they are just files `p` or `pas` will do